# How do I sign up for Area 51 when I get a completing redirect page?

Tags: discussion, support, area-51, firefox, sign-up

I want to sign up for Area 51 however, I always get stuck with this page, is their something that can be done about this? Is there something I am missing?

> [image: “Completing log in to Area 51/You will be redirected automatically”]

I want to propose a new site but getting in is a hassle.

Chrome allows me to find the sign in page but Firefox does not. What is going on and what could be done to fix this?

Comment: I just plain get a "not resolved" when trying to sign up

Comment: You seem to have an account: https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/204509/ben-madison could it be that your browser doesn't like to be redirected by javascript?

Comment: @rene i do now but i went through chrome i need to get into firefox i trust it more then chrome